# Does $\lim_{q\to \infty }f(q)$ has sense where $q\in \mathbb Q$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, notation

I wrote in a previous exam $$\lim_{\underset{q\in \mathbb Q}{q\to \infty} }f(q)=1\neq 0 =\lim_{\underset{r\in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q}{r\to \infty }}f(r),$$ but my teacher told me that such limit has no sense, but I don't understand why. Is that really have no sense ? And if yes, why ?

Comment: The first limit means $$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists x\in\mathbb R\quad\forall q\in\mathbb Q\quad q>x\implies|f(q)-1|<\epsilon$$ while the second limit means $$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists x\in\mathbb R\quad\forall r\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\quad r>x\implies|f(r)|<\epsilon$$ hence I fail to see the problem.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the exam problem and your answer?

Comment: Maybe he/she just wanted you to write it out as @Did wrote?

Comment: This is to second @JoeyZou's request.

Comment: And a third: You should show us the paper. There's no problem with what you wrote in this post. But what you wrote in this post is not exactly what appears on your paper - it's impossible to comment on how the paper was graded without seeing the paper itself. Seeing the paper, _not_ your description of what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $E\subseteq A\subseteq\Bbb R,$ $f:A\to\Bbb R,$ and $a,L\in\Bbb R.$

When we say $$\lim_{\underset{x\in E}{x\to \infty} }f(x)=L,$$ we mean that $E$ (and so $A$) is unbounded above in $\Bbb R,$ and that $$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists M:\forall x\in E,x>M\implies\bigl|f(x)-L\bigr|<\epsilon.$$

When we say $$\lim_{\underset{x\in E}{x\to a} }f(x)=L,$$ we mean that $a$ is a limit point of $E$ (and so of $A$), and that $$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0:\forall x\in E,0<|x-a|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-L\bigr|<\epsilon.$$

Both are perfectly sensible. We can also talk about one-sided $E$-limits, and limits as $x$ decreases without bound in $E$.

Now, it's possible that limits of this sort weren't part of the context of your course, so "don't make sense" as far as the *given definitions of the course* are concerned.

It could also be that the definitions *are* in the context of the course, but that your answer doesn't really address the question--without knowing what the question was, that's impossible for anyone here to say.